# Images not moving with columns (despite being set to "Move and Size With Cells")

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to keep the pictures in a table alongside the table once I delete the fist four columns. I have set each of their location properties to "Move and Size with Cells" however they still do not move when I do the above programatically (it works when done by manually)

Within my program I save a copy of the workbook, enter into that workbook and delete the first four columns, and then save that workbook to html. Unfortunately when I delete the first four columns, the photos never move alongside them.

```
'Sets which sheets to search through and update
 sheetList = Array("CH01", "CH02", "CH03", "CH04", "CH05", "CH06", "CH07", 
 "CH08", "CH09")

 Application.ScreenUpdating = False

 'Saves and opens new workbook to process and convert to html. Workbook 
 name is skew number.xlsm

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs _
 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.xlsm"

 Workbooks.Open (ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.xlsm")

 For sheetNum = LBound(sheetList) To UBound(sheetList)
     'sets sh to each sheet in sheetList
     Set sh = ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(sheetList(sheetNum))

     'Deletes first four rows of each sheet in sheetList (only way to 
      successfully hide columns once converted to html)
     sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
     sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
     sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
     sh.Columns(1).EntireColumn.Delete
 Next

 Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:01:00"))

 ActiveWorkbook.Save

 'Saves temp workbook as html
 ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs _
 Filename:=ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\test.html", _
 FileFormat:=xlHtml

 ActiveWorkbook.Close False

 Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

As you can see, I have even made the program wait for a minute to give the photos a chance to update their position. I have also kept the screen from updating until the entire process is done, which was the only suggestion I found on another thread. I also set each picture property to "xlMoveAndSize" in a previous bit of code, and I am sure that their location preference is updating to that.

Comment: If you perform these steps manually do you get the desired outcome?

Comment: Yep, everything works fine

Comment: I'd start by removing the `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` - when it hits the `Wait` does it look OK?

Comment: @TimWilliams I can't really watch it work. I removed the screen updating line but it still shows me just a blank white screen and says at the top (Not Responding) for the entire time it runs. BTW I have also tried placing the photos entirely in one cell each, that didn't do anything either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this - activating each sheet may allow for the shapes to mave as the columns are deleted.

```
Dim sheetList, wbCopy As Workbook, copyName As String
Dim wbOrig As Workbook, shtName

'Sets which sheets to search through and update
sheetList = Array("CH01", "CH02", "CH03", "CH04", "CH05", _
                  "CH06", "CH07", "CH08", "CH09")

Set wbOrig = ActiveWorkbook
copyName = wbOrig.Path & "\test.xlsm"
wbOrig.SaveCopyAs Filename:=copyName

Set wbCopy = Workbooks.Open(copyName)
wbCopy.Activate

For Each shtName In sheetList
    With wbCopy.Sheets(shtName)
        .Activate
        DoEvents
        .Range("A1:D1").EntireColumn.Delete
        DoEvents
     End With
 Next

Application.Wait Now + TimeValue("0:00:10")

With wbCopy
    .Save
    .SaveAs Filename:=Replace(copyName, ".xlsm", ".html"), _
              FileFormat:=xlHtml
    .Close False
End With
```

Comment: Hmm, thats a good idea. I will try this now. I am currently trying to save it as a single file webpage (.mht) in case accessing the separate files is what is slowing it down.

Comment: Wow it worked! Thanks a ton, man. I've been working on this part for three or four days now.